# Predict function Usage with pre() ,Rulefit package

Tags: r, predict

I was trying the rulefit implemenatation in caret using the `pre()` function for a classification task. I used the below command to train the model

```
fit = pre(output~.,data=train)
```

I presume that the fit object created is a model, which has 'rules and original features' as its predictors and can be used in predicting on test data.

I am not clear on how to use this model to predict the output on the test data.

I tried the predict command `predict(fit,test_data)` to predict on `test_data`, the result that get is numeric vector, which has values ranging from .9 to 1.9

It would be helpful if someone can guide me on this.I would like if the fit object created is a model, and if yes how to use that to predict on testdata

Regards,
JJ

Answer (score 1):

If `output` is a binary factor, you should specify `family = binomial` in the call to function `pre()`. Otherwise, a gaussian response distribution will be assumed by default (as is the case with most supervised learning methods in R). Make sure `output` is coded as a binary factor  in `train`. See also `?pre`.

The predicted values returned are on the scale of the linear predictor, by default, so they can take values from -Inf to Inf. To obtain predicted probabilities, you need to specify `type = "response"`, or `type = "class"` for predicted class. See also `?predict.pre`.

A short tutorial on package **`pre`** can be found here: https://github.com/marjoleinF/pre

Answer (score 0):

From the reference manual of `pre` package:

use `predict.pre(pre_obj, newdata)`

Comment: Thanks for the help ,I tried this command, but got the error  'could not find function "predict.pre"'.

Comment: If fit = pre(output~.,data=train) was run successfully, predict(fit, newdata = test_data) should do the trick.